# How to remove histogram bar labels for 0-values in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm creating histogram bar plots and I'm adding labels to the different categories with the value percentage. I wonder if it is possible to remove labels when the percentage value is 0, and if so, how?

For instance, the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure (figsize = (8.0, 6.0))

labels = [ "exp1", "exp2", "exp3", "exp4" ]
data_REF = [5, 4, 1, 1]
data_PAR = [1, 0, 0, 1]
data_OTH = [3, 1, 1, 1]

# Convert to numpy objects and calculate percentuals
data_REF = np.asarray(data_REF)
data_PAR = np.asarray(data_PAR)
data_OTH = np.asarray(data_OTH)
data_TOTALS = data_REF + data_PAR + data_OTH
data_pREF = 100 * data_REF / data_TOTALS
data_pPAR = 100 * data_PAR / data_TOTALS
data_pOTH = 100 * data_OTH / data_TOTALS

# Generate horizontal 100% stacked bar chart, with data bar labels
bREF  = plt.barh (labels, data_pREF, color="blue", edgecolor="blue", height=1)
bREF_ = plt.bar_label (bREF, label_type='center', color="white", fmt='%.2f')
bPAR  = plt.barh (labels, data_pPAR, left=data_pREF, color="white", edgecolor="gray", height=1)
bPAR_ = plt.bar_label (bPAR, label_type='center', color="darkgray", fmt='%.2f')
bOTH  = plt.barh (labels, data_pOTH, left=data_pREF+data_pPAR, color="red", edgecolor="red", height=1)
bOTH_ = plt.bar_label (bOTH, label_type='center', color="white", fmt='%.2f')
plt.legend ([bREF, bPAR, bOTH], ["REF", "On par", "OTH"], bbox_to_anchor=(0, -0.05), loc="upper center", mode="expand", fontsize='small', frameon=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig ("test.png")
plt.close (fig=None)
```

generates the following figure. And I'd like to get rid of the 0.00 label in rows "exp1" and "exp4".

[image: Result for the attached script]

Comment: `from itertools import compress` then change to : `bPAR  = plt.barh (list(compress(labels, data_pPAR>0)), data_pPAR[data_pPAR>0], left=data_pREF[data_pPAR>0], color="white", edgecolor="gray", height=1)
`

Comment: Thanks @HMH1013 -- but when using your solution I also loose the 33.33 and 11.11 from top and bottom rows, respectively.

Comment: I didn't lose the label for these two values,  here is the result I have : https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/04/04/kk927.png. Maybe you changed the line `bPAR_  = plt.bar_label... ` , just copy the code and change the line `bPAR  = plt.barh ...`

Comment: Thanks @HMH1013 -- I revisited this and it works now. I must had miss-typed something. Please, write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ Harald If it works, that's fine, actually I'm too lazy to write an answer..